# How to use Appsflyer API in Python to get metrics

Tags: python, appsflyer

Basically, I want to use **Appsflyer API** by **Python** to get metrics. I tried to find some documentation about this but It seems like there is no support for this. If it possible please give me an example of how to use Python to get metrics on Appsflyer?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I searched on google how to use Python to get metrics from Appsflyer but there was no result

Comment: You don't have a single line of code yet?

Comment: Of course not. Do you understand my question? I do not know how to get started. Now I am asking for directions

Comment: Unluckily SO is not a platform for giving directions. It is for specific answer to specific questions. And it is expected that you have written some code or at least have done intensive research on the topic. Just a few Google queries is not enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several different APIs AppsFlyer offers to get metrics. These include [Push API](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207034356-Push-APIs-Installation-and-Conversion-Notification-APIs), [Pull API](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207034346-Pull-APIs-Pulling-AppsFlyer-Reports-by-APIs), and [Master API](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/213223166-Master-API-Customizable-Aggregated-Data-API-). Below is an explanation on how to get metrics using the Pull API including a sample Python script.

Review this documentation found in the AppsFlyer Help Center:

- Documentation for using the Pull API to export data out of AppsFlyer could be found here: [Introduction to Pull API](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207034346-Pull-APIs-Pulling-AppsFlyer-Reports-by-APIs)
- Examples on pulling Raw Data found here: [Pulling Raw Data with the Pull API](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207034346-Pull-APIs-Pulling-AppsFlyer-Reports-by-APIs#Raw)
- Examples on pulling Performance Reports found here: [Pulling Performance Reports with the Pull API](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207034346-Pull-APIs-Pulling-AppsFlyer-Reports-by-APIs#Performance)

Here is an example of a url you could paste into the browser that would generate a csv file:

```
https://hq.appsflyer.com/export/<APP ID HERE>/installs_report/v5?api_token=<API TOKEN HERE>&from=<FROM DATE HERE>&to=<TO DATE HERE>
```

- Both *from_date* and *to_date* should be entered in this format 'yyyy-mm-dd' (without the quotes)
- The *app_id* and *api_token* are available via the AppsFlyer dashboard, (*app_id* is also available outside of the dashboard)
- Other examples could be found in the links provided above.

Here is a sample version of a script in Python:

```
import requests
import os
import json
import urllib

def main():

    #ENTER PARAMETERS BELOW
    api_endpoint = "https://hq.appsflyer.com/export/"
    api_token = "" #Enter API Token here ; found under "Integration" > "API Access" in the platform
    app_id = ""         #Enter app id here ; Apple IDs look like id123456789 ; Andriod IDs look like com.myapp
    report_name = ""    #Enter name here ; e.g. "installs_report"

    from_dt = ""    #e.g. "2019-01-01"
    to_dt ""        #e.g. = "2019-01-07"

    #NO NEED TO MODIFY CODE BELOW
    query_params = {
        "api_token": api_token,
        "from": str(from_dt),
        "to": str(to_dt)
        }


    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(query_params)

    request_url = api_endpoint + app_id + "/" report_name + "/v5?" + query_string

    print(request_url)

    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(request_url)

    with open("appsflyer_installs_data.csv","wb") as fl:
        fl.write(resp.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Once you configure the parameters correctly, you can use the above script to generate a file called "appsflyer_installs_data.csv".

There are other parameters you can add to get additional fields and filter the data. Information on this could be found in the [article shared above](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207034346-Pull-APIs-Pulling-AppsFlyer-Reports-by-APIs). These queries are also held to an [API Policy](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207034346-Pull-APIs-Pulling-AppsFlyer-Reports-by-APIs#raw-api-policy-and-usage-limitations).

As a reminder, this is just one example of how you could get data out of AppsFlyer. For others make sure to review support.appsflyer.com.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, there is no official Python SDK for AppsFlyer, but on Github, you can find unofficial API-clients:

- https://github.com/YuriyOrlov/pyappsflyer
- https://github.com/fredericojordan/appsflyer-python
- https://github.com/ariarijp/python-appsflyer